# Lowest Overhead When Returning Linq to SQL across a WCF Service?

Tags: vb.net, linq, wcf

Im looking to optimize my WCF Service. Im using net.tcp connection.

I have a linq to SQL query that returns a list of a person object:

```
 Public Function GetPeople(ByVal ChunkSize As Integer, ByVal Offset As Integer) As List(Of NG.person) Implements RiseSync.GetPeople
    Dim db As New NGDataContext
    Dim tmpList As New List(Of NG.person)
    tmpList = (From p In db.persons Order By p.create_timestamp Descending Skip Offset Take ChunkSize).ToList()
    Return tmpList
End Function
```

I access this across the WCF interface, its slow. Would i see improved performance converting it all to an array, or converting it to a datatable before transferring it across the pipe?

What would be best practice? The query will return about 50k results.

**UPDATE:**
Edited the code to show exactly what i am using. The reason for some many records is this is for an initial data load. I use a offset and take to chunk the data into smaller bits, but the total operation needs to process around 50K records. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you need 50k returned? How applying some more filters to the query to return a reasonable amount?

Comment: You have 50k results after paging?! Also, I don't think your code compiles at all.

Comment: What is "the total operation" ? You'll never get more than `ChunkSize` records at a time.

Comment: I agree with some of the comments above. Not sure you need to return 50k results, and you would see much better results if you applied filters to the query. However, if it absolutely necessary to return 50K records, how about a paging technique? that way you could return the data in chucks...

Comment: Does the code above implement paging in the best manor? On the other end of the pipe I get the record count split it up into chunks and make a request for each chunk. It's still horribly slow using net tcp. Sadly I need to sync and entire table so the code above is for the first initial sync subsequent syncs filter based upon created and modified timestamps. I looked at merge replication and other sql solutions but I need to manipulate the data and pull in data from many different clients and then store it in my data store so it seems like wcf would be best. Are there any other ways I can impr